# How can I add a password into a "sudo" command?

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, command

I want to use [When Gnome Scheduler](http://almostearthling.github.io/when-command/) to run this:

```
sudo service fancontrol start
```

As "sudo" needs a password, how can I add it into the command, so that it can be run successfully? 
Each time Mint resumes after suspension, it needs to be run again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wondering how to get a password into a script I'd suggest modifying sudoers (or, even better [because cleaner], adding a separate file for this purpose to `/etc/sudoers.d/`).

Something like (assuming matthew's your username):

```
cat /etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol
matthew    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service fancontrol start
```

Make sure it has the right permissions, and best to use visudo to edit it (that makes sure you don't have syntax errors in the file).

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol
```

Comment: Do you mean using the command "chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol" on When Gnome Scheduler after adding the separate file "fancontrol" into the folder "/etc/sudoers.d/"?

Comment: I added the separate file "fancontrol" into "/etc/sudoers.d/". When I run "sudo service fancontrol start", it says the following: ">>> /etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin".

Comment: I tried to use "sudo nemo /" to delete "fancontrol", but I got the same error. How can I delete it?

Comment: Actually, I fail to run any "sudo" command. What should I do?

Comment: I just booted from a Mint Live SD card. I selected "Show Hidden Files" and went to "/etc/sudoers.d/" on the HDD, but "fancontrol" was not there. I am now using Mint installed on the HDD, and "fancontrol" is still in "/etc/sudoers.d/". Why can't I find it via Mint Live? How can I delete it?

Comment: I just managed to delete "/etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol" via a Lubuntu Live SD card, and "sudo" has returned to normal on Mint. Why couldn't I use Mint to delete "fancontrol", which caused errors on Mint? I might have had to re-install Mint if it had not been for Lubuntu.

Comment: Glad you managed to recover. I assume you weren't using `visudo`? And no, the idea was to apply those perms to the newly created file in `/etc/sudoers.d` ... Not sure what went wrong for you there.

Comment: Can you tell how to use "visudo"? I know nothing about it.

Comment: I just found the command "sudo visudo" but don't know how to use it on Terminal.

Comment: Do mean I should add the following lines via "sudo visudo"? If so, under which line should it be added?
cat /etc/sudoers.d/fancontrol
matthew    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service fancontrol start

Comment: I have asked [a new question here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499729/)